# Is it possible to initialize a bool with True?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types

I am defining a variable through an empty declaration:

```
In [1]: a = bool()

In [2]: a
Out[2]: False
```

Is it possible to force an initialization of `True`?

---

Note: I know I can simply have `a = True` or `a = bool(True)` but I will be initializing several variables with specific types, something like

```
x = dict()
for v in [('a', int), ('b', float), ('c', bool)]
    x[v[0]] = v[1]()
```

The defaults for `int`, `float`, etc. are OK, I would just prefer to specifically have a `bool` initialized as `True`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to customize your `bool`:

```
from functools import partial

my_bool = partial(bool, 1)

print(my_bool())
# True
```

And you can use it in your code as:

```
x = dict()
for v in [('a', int), ('b', float), ('c', my_bool)]
    x[v[0]] = v[1]()
```

You could also use a lambda (credit: @tobias_k):

```
my_bool = lambda: True
```

Comment: Ah excellent - I did not know `partial`, very useful function. Thank you.

Comment: Or a lambda: `my_bool = lambda: True`

Comment: @tobias_k I kept thinking of a work around with `bool`. Sleek! Thanks.

Comment: You're going to be surprised if you try to do `my_bool(0)`

Comment: @eugeney I wouldn't call it a surprise. OP has a use case. And if one did that, it will break like every other function that does not take positional arguments.

Comment: The `lambda: True` version can even be used directly in the tuple, without going though the extra variable. Very nice.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a possible solution for you with the flexibility for other special default values

```
typeDefaults = {bool: True}

for v in [('a', int), ('b', float), ('c', bool)]:
    x[v[0]] = typeDefaults[v[1]] if v[1] in typeDefaults else v[1]()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could map the types you want to change the default values for to your own functions:

```
>>> defaults = {bool: lambda: True}
>>> x = {}
>>> for k, v in [('a', int), ('b', float), ('c', bool)]:
...     x[k] = defaults.get(v, v)()
... 
>>> x
{'a': 0, 'c': True, 'b': 0.0}
```

or using a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> {k: defaults.get(v, v)() for k, v in [('a', int), ('b', float), ('c', bool)]}
{'a': 0, 'c': True, 'b': 0.0}
```